# Sidekiq - Deleting scheduled jobs when task is deleted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I schedule reminder emails when a user creates a task for a certain date using the following code in the create action:

```
if @post.save
  EmailWorker.perform_in(@time.minutes, @post.id)
end
```

I want to delete the scheduled reminder mail whenever the associated task is deleted. I tried using a model method on `before_destroy`:

```
before_destroy :destroy_sidekiq_job

def destroy_sidekiq_job
  post_id = self.id
  queue = Sidekiq::Queue.new('critical')
  queue.each do |job|
    if job.klass == 'EmailWorker' && job.args.first == post_id
      job.delete
    end
  end
end
```

However, the jobs aren't deleted from the queue. Any suggestions for me to fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The scheduled jobs are not within a queue yet, use `Sidekiq::ScheduledSet` to find the scheduled jobs:

```
def destroy_sidekiq_jobs
  scheduled = Sidekiq::ScheduledSet.new
  scheduled.each do |job|
    if job.klass == 'EmailWorker' && job.args.first == id
      job.delete
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Just a quick question - why aren't they in the queue yet?

Comment: Only jobs that are ready to be run are in a queue.  Before that they live in ScheduledSet and are moved into a queue by the scheduler.

Answer (score 6):

Don't do this.  Let Sidekiq execute the job but verify the post exists and is current **when the email job is run**.

```
def perform(post_id)
  post = Post.find_by_id(post_id)
  return unless post

  ...
end
```

Comment: this works well. how would i go about adding a check for updated_at? not sure how to grab the variable for updated at and compare it

Comment: You mean like `return if post.updated_at > some_date`?

Comment: yes but the check would be post.updated_at == quene.updated_at. i passed in updated_at as an arg that redis saves along with the post id.